# Jquery : Tiptip content loaded in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tiptip

i would load content of tiptip from ajax but this doesn't work :-/

This is the code :

```
<div class="maclasse"><a href="#" ajaxparam="monparametre" title="">aaaaaaaa</a></div>
<script>
$(function() {
$(".maclasse a").tipTip({   delay : 200,
        maxWidth : "350px",
        context : this,
        content: function (e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../front/toto.php?" + $(this).attr('ajaxparam'),
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            e.content.html(response);
                        }
                    });
                    return 'Chargement...';
                }
    });
});
</script>
```

2 errors insolved from my script :

- the url called by ajax would be **front/toto.php?monparametre** but it is **front/toto.php?undefined**
- in case of ajax success, the error **e.content is undefined** is catch

If someone knows the issue, i would be very very happy :-)

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using $(this) inside ajax handler won't work, because it will be assigned to the ajax function itself, and not to html page. For the second question, try to log the response to the console and check if it has the value you are looking for, maybe it's some sort of misspell error. The code:

```
<div class="maclasse"><a href="#" ajaxparam="monparametre" title="">aaaaaaaa</a></div>
<script>
var that = this;    
$(function() {

$(".maclasse a").tipTip({   delay : 200,
    maxWidth : "350px",
    context : this,
    content: function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../front/toto.php?" + $(that).attr('ajaxparam'),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        e.content.html(response);
                    }
                });
                return 'Chargement...';
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your message
- "response" is correcte, i see the right response with firebug, it's "e.content" which is undefined
- "that" doesn't work neither :-/, it's the same thing => toto.php?undefined